# Getting an error "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found" when try to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ on Windows 8.1

Tags: xampp

Apache and MySQL is running but failed to open the localhost i.e 127.00.1 from the browser

Comment: Can you try to simply access http://127.00.1 and see if that connects.  If not, make sure the port selected in the Apache configuration is the default port (80) and also look at its log.

Comment: There is a typo in ip address it should be 127.0.0.1  . Also open xampp control panel, maybe it runs apache under other port i.e. 8888 so in this case address should be http://127.0.0.1:8888